# Redirect url if referrer isn't current domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, referrer

I am trying to redirect to another page if any users try to access the members area via url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?(?!test\.jason\.ca) [NC]
Rewriterule ^ http://test\.jason\.ca [R,L]
```

So I want it to kick them to the home page if they try to access any url without the referrer being the domain name. I know I am doing this wrong, but I don't know what yet. Any ideas?

EDIT: So it's not exactly like what I posted up above apparently. I forgot to include this portion but this is how it is in my .htaccess exactly:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
AddType text/x-component .htc


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?(?!test\.jason\.ca) [NC]
Rewriterule ^ http://test\.jason\.ca [R,L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Just FYI, using the referer for any kind of validation is generally a rather poor idea, as user agents can pretty much supply whatever they want. It's trivial to spoof, but legitimate users with browser not reporting referral information will be annoyed. I'd advise against this.

Comment: What do you recommend using instead? I'm trying to prevent anyone from accessing my wordpress uploads folder, unless they are authorized to access it (signed into wordpress)

Comment: It depends on how secure it should be, but I'd suggest a PHP-based solution. Session. And I'm sure there are various WordPress authentication plugins if you'd rather not roll your own.

Comment: Well, I'm sure there must be a way I can access the session or cookie that Wordpress is already using to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the referer rules above the wordpress rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?(?!test\.jason\.ca) [NC]
Rewriterule ^ http://test\.jason\.ca [R,L] 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```